# Working with Zipped folder from memory

Tags: c#, .net, io, zip, memory-mapped-files

I'm making an XNA game, which uses a lot (currently ~2800) of small resource files. It has become a problem to move them around from place to place unarchived, so I thought maybe I could just zip them and make the game unzip them automatically, into memory, preferably. I don't need the writing capability yet, right now only reading.

Is there an easy way to unzip a folder into memory and access those files just like, or as simple as the regular files on disk?

---

I've been reading some similar questions and I see many people say that the OS (Windows in my case) can handle file caching better than a ram drive. I'm just going for unzipping and reading files for now, but in future I might need to modify or create new files, and I'd like it to be quick and seamless for the user. Maybe I should take a different approach at solving my current problem, taking in account my future goal?

Comment: feel free to change the tags to more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried this but if you want to be able to zip/unzip in memory, you could just use a `MemoryStream` and pass that into a library (eg https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib). Things you'll probably need to remember, are you just moving a bottleneck to a different bottleneck?

You could also try something like the approach with Sprites in HTML. You combine all your Zip's into 1 with an Index to where in the file they are. Then you move your FileStream.Position to the location for the resource you are looking for, read (the amount you need) then do what you need with it. You'd need to make sure that if you rebuild any you make something rebuild all your combining indexes etc. Then you just would be copying 1 file around, it just so happens that inside that file you have ~2800 smaller segments of interest.

Comment: I believe the memory 'bottleneck' us huge compared to hdd one. I tried a ram disk, and it's super fast, but I need something I can deploy for end-users. I think just zipping the entire assets folder will do the trick, it's what zip is for.

Comment: could you use a Zip's filesystem capability to store all your resources in 1 file? You could then Unzip into a memorystream

Comment: Ah, if that's what you're talking about, then I guess not. But would I need that with the files in memory? Well, I'll try MemoryStream approach a bit later.